# How To Set NULL is 0 in SQL Dynamic Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I developed one dynamic pivot table, and I set  `ISNULL = 0.00`.
The query is given below

```
SELECT DISTINCT hdr.EmpNo,hdr.FirstName AS Name,
                ISNULL(TBL.shortname,'')AS shortname, 
                ISNULL(TBL.Amount,0.00) AS Amount,
                TBL.Adtype INTO #Temp FROM  tbl1 AS hdr
LEFT JOIN tbl2 TBL  ON TBL.EmpNo = hdr.EmpNo
DECLARE @Ded AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Ded = STUFF((SELECT ', ISNULL( ' + QUOTENAME(c.shortname) + ', 0.00 )AS ' + 
            QUOTENAME(c.shortname)  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT shortname FROM #Temp 
            WHERE ISNULL(shortname,'') <> '' AND Adtype = 2) AS c ORDER BY 
            shortname  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'') 
SET @Query = 'SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpNo ASC) AS  
              VARCHAR(100)) AS [S.No],EmpNo,Name,' + @Ded +' FROM  #Temp 
              PIVOT(SUM(Amount)  FOR shortname IN (' + @Ded + ')) AS PVTTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

But it displays the following error, and line 3 doesn't not have a "(".

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>                      Incorrect syntax near '('.

Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: in SSMS set "Results to text" in the Query menu and add `Print @Query` , comment out `EXEC sp_executesql @Query1` and show the output in the question

Comment: Print @Query Is Given Following Result , But EXEC Query Given Same Same That Error:.  --->"SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpNo ASC) AS  VARCHAR(100)) AS [S.No],EmpNo,Name,  ISNULL( [BULD-SOC], 0.00 ) AS [BULD-SOC],  ISNULL( [CANTEEN], 0.00 ) AS [CANTEEN], ISNULL( [CLUB], 0.00 ) AS [CLUB],  ISNULL( [FEST-ADV], 0.00 ) AS [FEST-ADV],   FROM  #Temp      PIVOT(SUM(dedAmount)  FOR shortname IN ( ISNULL( [BULD-SOC], 0.00 ) AS [BULD-SOC],   ISNULL( [CANTEEN], 0.00 ) AS [CANTEEN], ISNULL( [CLUB], 0.00 ) AS [CLUB], ISNULL( [FEST-ADV], 0.00 ) AS [FEST-ADV], ))  AS PVTTable" <--

Comment: you have an extra comma after `ISNULL( [FEST-ADV], 0.00 ) AS [FEST-ADV]` twice

Comment: It's My mistake In Command. don't have ","In the  Procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with @der variable use in `in` clause.
you are setting column name with `isnull` and in `in` clause, it is not supported.

Please try below query.

```
;with tbl1 as 
(
select 1 EmpNo,'Emp1' FirstName
union all 
select 2 EmpNo,'Emp2' FirstName
),
tbl2 as 
(
select 'EMP1' shortname,100 Amount, 2 Adtype,1 EmpNo
union all
select 'EMP2' shortname,100 Amount, 2 Adtype,2 EmpNo
)

SELECT DISTINCT hdr.EmpNo,hdr.FirstName AS Name,
                ISNULL(TBL.shortname,'')AS shortname, 
                ISNULL(TBL.Amount,0.00) AS Amount,
                TBL.Adtype INTO #Temp FROM  tbl1 AS hdr
LEFT JOIN tbl2 TBL  ON TBL.EmpNo = hdr.EmpNo


DECLARE @Ded AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='' ,@Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @Wer AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
SET @Ded = STUFF((SELECT ', ISNULL( ' +  QUOTENAME(c.shortname) + ', 0.00 )AS ' + 
            QUOTENAME(c.shortname)  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT shortname FROM #Temp 
            WHERE ISNULL(shortname,'') <> '' AND Adtype = 2) AS c ORDER BY 
            shortname  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'') 

SET @Wer = STUFF((SELECT ',  ' +  QUOTENAME(c.shortname)  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT shortname FROM #Temp 
            WHERE ISNULL(shortname,'') <> '' AND Adtype = 2) AS c ORDER BY 
            shortname  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'') 


SET @Query = 'SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpNo ASC) AS  
              VARCHAR(100)) AS [S.No],EmpNo,Name,' + @Ded +' FROM  #Temp 
              PIVOT(SUM(Amount)  FOR shortname IN (' + @Wer + ')) AS PVTTable'
--print @Query

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: Some Column have  a NULL Value so Set Null =0.00 , It's  Main Problem Of the Result.

Comment: Yes and to handle null, I have separated "@Ded" into two parts @Ded and "@Wer".